# Having a comment obtain a community_id as well

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I've tried figuring out the issue behind not being able to save the community_id I hope someone can help me with.

**MODELS**

**User**

```
has_one :profile
has_many :communities, dependent: :destroy
has_many :comment, dependent: :destroy
```

**Community**

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :finders]

has_many :comments
belongs_to :user
```

**Comment**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :community
belongs_to :profile
```

**CONTROLLERS**

**Communities**

```
def index
 @communities = Community.all
 @comment = Comment.new
 @comments = Comment.all
end

def create
 @community = Community.new(community_params)
 @community.user_id = session[:user_id]

 if @community.save
  flash[:notice] = "Post Created"
 else
  flash[:alert] = "Error post not created"
 end
 redirect_to "/"
end

def new
 @community = Community.new
end

def edit
 @community = Community.friendly.find(params[:id])
end

def show
 @comment = Comment.new
 @comments = Comment.all
 @community = Community.friendly.find(params[:id])
 @current_user = User.find(session[:user_id])
end

def update
 @community = Community.friendly.find(params[:id])
 if @community.update(params[:comment])
  flash[:notice] = "post updated"
 else
  flash[:alert] = "post not updated"
 end
end

def destroy
 @community = Community.friendly.find(params[:id])
 if @community.destroy
  flash[:notice] = "Post was thrown away"
 else
  flash[:alert] = "Post was not deleted"
 end
 redirect_to "/"
end

private

def community_params
 params.require(:community).permit(:user_id, :title, :bio)
end
```

**Comments**

```
def index
 @comments = Comment.all
end

def create
 @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
 @comment.user_id = session[:user_id]

 if @comment.save && @comment.community_id
  flash[:notice] = "Comment has been posted"
 else
  flash[:alert] = @comment.errors.full_messages
 end

 redirect_to :back
end

def new
 @comment = Comment.new
end

def show
 @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
end

def destroy
 @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
 @comment.destroy
 redirect_to :back
end

private

def comment_params
 params.require(:comment).permit(:text, :user_id, :community_id, :profile_id)
end
```

**VIEWS**

**comments/_new**

```
<%= form_for @comment do |f| %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :community_id %>
 <%= f.text_area :text, placeholder: "Enter New Comment Here ...", :cols => 50, :rows => 3, :class => 'text_field_message', :id => 'new_comment' %>
 <%= f.submit :class => 'new_comment_button' %>
<% end %>
```

Whenever I check my console I notice the user_id gets registered with the comment but community_id is nil. Could someone point me in the right direction or help me understand where I made an error. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: And what value should community id have if current_user has more than one community?

Comment: @BroiSatse Noticed my entire code wasn't written. I have the value written as <%= f.hidden_field :community_id, value: community_id %>

Comment: And where does `community_id` value come from? There is nothing in the code which could explain how to you want to bind those two record together. My initial thought wa that you have nested resources, but the rest of your comments controller seems to differ with the idea.

Comment: I can't see any value assigned to the `hidden_field community_id`

Comment: In which view you are calling that partial form?

Comment: @Pavan I'm calling that partial into the communities/show view. I would also like to render the comment/_new partial onto profile/show page as well since  user should be able to create a comment either in a community or a profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly,

```
#app/models/user.rb
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy  #-> this should be plural.
```

---

You have no value in your `community_id` input attribute:

```
#app/controllers/comments_controller.rb
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @comment = Comment.new
   end
end

#app/views/comments/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @comment do |f| %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :community_id, params[:community_id] %>
<% end %>
```

I am assuming you're passing your `:community_id` parameter through the routes (IE `url.com/communities/:community_id/comments/new`)

---

I would do the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :communities do
   resources :comments
end

#app/controllers/comments_controller.rb
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @comment = Comment.new
   end

   def create
      @comment = Comment.new comment_params
      @comment.save
   end

   private

   def comment_params
       params.require(:comment).permit(:text).merge(user_id: current_user.id, community_id: params[:community_id])
   end
end
```

This will give you the ability to use the following view:

```
#app/views/comments/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @comment do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_area :text, placeholder: "Enter New Comment Here ...", :cols => 50, :rows => 3, :class => 'text_field_message', :id => 'new_comment' %>
   <%= f.submit :class => 'new_comment_button' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and your own input how you would proceed. I have a question though. Currently, I'm trying to make it for comment to appear either in the community page  site.com/communities/id (show) or the profile page site.com/profile/user_name(id). For that reason I haven't merged the two. Would you recommend merging both and add a different model for users to post on each other profiles or recommend sticking to using comments as the central model for users to comment in a community page or a user profile page? Thank you again for all your help and inputs.